# Sql Server Group by and Case When

Tags: sql-server-2012, group-by, case

Suppose we have this table contents:

```
id  type  value
1    A    X1122
1    B    JJHJU
2    A    POIUY
2    C    YUHGF
```

and I want to get this solution by a select:

```
id  valueA  valueB  valueC
1   X1122   JJHJU   NULL
2   POIUY   NULL    YUHGF
```

My first attempt was this:

```
SELECT id, CASE type WHEN A THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueA
, CASE type WHEN B THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueB
, CASE type WHEN C THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueC
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

but it returns me the error

> The columns 'type' and 'value' needs to be in GROUP BY statement

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called PIVOT:

```
declare @data table(id int, valtype char(1), val varchar(10))
insert into @data(id, valtype, val) values
(1, 'A', 'X1122'), (1, 'B', 'JJHJU'), (2, 'A', 'POIUY'), (2, 'C', 'YUHGF')

Select id, valueA = piv.A, valueB = piv.B, valueC = piv.C
From @data
Pivot ( 
    max(val)
    for valtype in ([A], [B], [C])
) as piv
```

Output:

```
1   X1122   JJHJU   NULL
2   POIUY   NULL    YUHGF
```

PIVOT on [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)